# Background image for link is not loading

Tags: html, image, background, hyperlink

This is not working. Only the span string is displayed. Images are not loading. While debugging in firefox, no entries in div#social a.fb {}. If I remove the `background-image: url(../../images/job/facebook.jpg");`, then the class will load with full entries.

```
<div id="social">
   <span>follow us</span>
   <a class="fb" title="Like us on Facebook" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hiring-Steps/155650987881886">Facebook</a>   
</div>


div#social a.fb {
    background-image: url(../../images/job/facebook.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You have a `"` at the end of the filename

Comment: Oh thanks. I wasted too much time on that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
background-image: url(../../images/job/facebook.jpg");
```

Remove the closing quote from the end or add the opening one. Maybe that is why the image is not loading.